# How can i make a div as non selectable from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my `div` as follows

```
<div class="menu" id="admindiv" runat="server">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">welcome to my site<!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="Reports.aspx">Reports</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Delete.aspx">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]-->
        </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to enable or disable on a page from code behind, means i would like to make this `div` as non selectable field on certain conditions. I tried this but i didn't get succeeded

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    admindiv.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;");
    admindiv.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
}
```

Comment: `DIV`'s can not be selected, so you can't make them enabled or  disabled! What do mean? Can you explain more please?

Comment: I would like to show the div on page but it should be non-selectable

Comment: You can't make a `DIV` non-selectable. If you want to make the links non-clickable, then I post the way.

Comment: Ok can you post for that

Comment: I sent you the way, but the security is not provided! Do you keep the `Reports.aspx` and `Delete.aspx` secure from anonymous access? However a user can type the `URL` in browser's address-bar (without needing the links above) and access the page. Keep them secure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a DIV non-selectable. If you want to make the links non-clickable, this is the code-snipt does it:

```
<div class="menu" id="admindiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">welcome to my site<!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1"  runat="server" Text="Reports" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="Link2"  runat="server" Text="Delete" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]-->
        </ul>
</div>
```

**AND** the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if(isAdmin) { // check for admin user
        Link1.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx";
        Link1.NavigateUr2 = "Delete.aspx";
    } else {
        Link1.NavigateUrl = "javascript:return void;";
        Link1.NavigateUr2 = "javascript:return void;";
    }

}
```

Comment: I am having a small question can i add an alert when navigation of the link is set to false

Comment: Yes you can, but it is an another question. Create a new question, put this question's link in new's body, and ask what you want. Also you can notify me about your new question by create a comment here.

Comment: Posted my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550914/how-to-display-an-alert-box-on-a-non-clickable-link-button

Comment: OK I'm so happy that you got your answer there. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Divs can be shown and hidden, but not disabled. If the div is visible its contents will be active unless you disable each item individually.

Another option to disabling each control is to create a new div that is transparent but sits on top of the part you want to disable, then just show / hide that div from the code behind.

However this is not a security mechanism, as anyone with a browser HTML developer plug-in (like firebug) can remove that div and gain access to the controls.

The best way to disable links in ASP.NET is to add an "onclick" event (works with linkbuttons and hyperlinks):

```
LinkButton1.Attributes["OnClick"] = “return false;”;
```